# Finding an object in a nested object/array structure

Tags: javascript, array, json

I have an app with a bunch of questions defined in a yaml file. For various reasons I would like the data to be divided into sections (`section_0`, `section_1`, `section_2` etc.). When I load this file into my js app I get an object that looks like this:

```
const questionData = {
  "section_0": {
    "items": [
      {
        "key": "0.0",
        "title": "Question one",
        "type": "integer"
      },
      {
        "key": "0.1",
        "title": "Question 0.1",
        "type": "integer"
      }
    ]
  },
  "section_1": {
    "items": [
      {
        "key": "1.0",
        "title": "Some title",
        "type": "integer",
        "options": {
          "1": "one",
          "2": "two",
          "3": "other option"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "1.1",
        "title": "Question 1.1",
        "description": "Longer description text",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "key": "1.2",
        "title": "Question 1.2",
        "type": "integer",
        "options": {
          "0": "option zero",
          "1": "option one",
          "2": "option two"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "1.3",
        "title": "Q 1.2",
        "type": "boolean",
        "options": {
          "true": "Yes",
          "false": "No"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "1.4",
        "title": "Question 1.4",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "key": "1.5",
        "title": "Question 1.5",
        "type": "integer"
      },
      {
        "key": "1.6",
        "title": "Question 1.6",
        "type": "integer"
      },
      {
        "key": "1.7",
        "title": "Q1.7",
        "type": "integer"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

(a lot more questions and sections in the actual app)

Now I would like to be able to query for a question by the key. I found/figured out two ways to do this. One is sort of home made and the other flattens the array using lodash.

Traversing the object:

```
function findByKey(data, key){
    if (data.hasOwnProperty('key') && data['key'] === key) {
      return data;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
      if (typeof data[Object.keys(data)[i]] === 'object') {
        let obj = findByKey(data[Object.keys(data)[i]], key);
        if (obj != null) {
          return obj;
        }
      }
    }

    return null;
}

findByKey(questionData, "0.1")
// => returns the object with the key "0.1"
```

Using lodash to create a flat array of objects:

```
const questionsArray = _.flatten(_.map(_.keys(questionData), function(val) {
  return questionData[val].items;
}));

_.find(questionsArray, function(obj) { return obj.key === "0.1" })
// => returns the object with the key "0.1"
```

Do I need to transform the questionData object like this just to be able to query for an object somewhere in the tree or am I missing some simpler solution (other than not creating the nested structure in the first place)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually have methods to normalize data in the format I want it so you don't have to iterate again.
If you want you can have Schema that provides you methods or access to the data using custom methods.

```
var questions = new QuestionsSchema(data); // Normalizes to preferred format    questions.getOriginal(); // => Access to the original object 
questions.getQuestion('0.1');    // =>      {"key": "0.0","title": "Question one","type": "integer"}
questions.getSection('section_1'); // => whole section
```

I like more the composed functions you build, is a more like functional way.